# How do I use the section Entry URL format for registerSiteRoutes() in a plugin?

Tags: plugin-development, plugins, sections, routes, routing

I'm trying to register a site route in my plugin based on the Entry URL format for a section chosen in the plugin settings.

So if it's the default news section in the Craft install the URL format stored in the database would be: `news/{postDate.year}/{slug}` or for an About single section it would be: `about`.

I want to add /login to the end of the url:

e.g. `news/2016/amazing-title/login` or `about/login`

Then use a login template (e.g. `news/_login`) in the section for this registered route.

I know how to manually do this with `registerSiteRoutes()` and the setting stored in a plugin service:

```
public function registerSiteRoutes()
{
    $section = craft()->pluginName->getSettingsSection();

    return array(
        $section . 'REGEX\/login' => $section . '/_login'
    );
}
```

What's the best way to convert the Entry URL format for the section into something that can be used in the return array of `registerSiteRoutes()`?

Comment: You can get a section's URL format like this: `$urlFormat = $section->getUrlFormat();` (provided `$section` is an instance of [`SectionModel`](https://craftcms.com/classreference/models/SectionModel)). Then, you just need a way to resolve URL format variables (i.e. `{slug}` or `{postDate.year}` to valid routing subpatterns, and append the '/login' to the result. Hopefully somebody a bit more versed in regex than myself will be able to help out :)

Comment: Thanks for that. I was hoping Craft maybe had a method for converting getUrlFormat() without resorting to my own regex.

Comment: Craft doesn't have a native method to do a conversion like that... it'd have to be custom logic.